# Workaround for cannot redeclare?

Tags: php, mysql, redeclare

I just finished getting this script working and I need to use it multiple times in the same page. However, when I use it a second time I get the error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_names() (previously declared. I looked around for an answer but all I could find was to use the once command but it doesn't seem to work with get. Here is the script:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass') or die("Database error");
mysql_select_db('dbname', $db);

$query = "SELECT pool FROM winners";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
if ($row['pool'] % 2) {
    echo "<h4>Result 1</h4>";
    $names = get_names(1);
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<h4>Result 2</h4>";
    $names = get_names(0);
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br/>";
    }
}

function get_names($pool_result)
{
$name_array = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid % 2 = $pool_result";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($name_array, $row['name']);
}

return $name_array;
```

}
    ?>

Answer (score 2):

It's an ugly hack but you can put this around the function:

```
if ( !function_exists("get_names") ) {

/// the function

}
```

The better way of course is to `include_once("includefile.php");`, with `includefile.php` containing the function in question (note: `includefile.php` also needs the opening and closing `<?php ?>` tags).

Comment: I just tried this and I'm still getting the same error. What parts exactly need to be put into the php file that I'm using include_once on?

Comment: the `function get_names($pool_result) { ... }` part. Or you could put that function in the file that is apparently including the script multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the function in `if(!function_exists('get_names'))`, or use `include_once` or `require_once` to include the file rather than `include` or fix your calling script to not include it twice (or more).

Answer (score 1):

Put the function definition into it's own file and call include (or require) once at the top of the page on that file.

**get_names** is getting defined more than once and so the second time raising a fatal error.

EDIT:

The only part that **needs** to be in it's own file is the function definition:

```
function get_names($pool_result)
{
    $name_array = array();

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid % 2 = $pool_result";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        array_push($name_array, $row['name']);

    return $name_array;
}
```

Though I and surely others would advocate further organization of the code, if you put that function in a file like, library.php or something and then `require_once('path/to/library.php')` it, you should be able to run the rest of it multiple times.

Comment: I just tried this and I'm still getting the same error. What parts exactly need to be put into the php file that I'm using include_once on?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass') or die("Database error");
mysql_select_db('dbname', $db);

$query = "SELECT pool FROM winners";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
if ($row['pool'] % 2) {
    echo "<h4>Result 1</h4>";
    $names = get_names(1);
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<h4>Result 2</h4>";
    $names = get_names(0);
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br/>";
    }
}
if(!function_exists("get_names")) {

  function get_names($pool_result)
  {
  $name_array = array();

  $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid % 2 = $pool_result";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      array_push($name_array, $row['name']);
  }

  return $name_array;
}
```